# Explanation on this FIRST function

Tags: parsing, programming-languages, grammar, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

LL(1) Grammar:

```
(1) Var -> ID DimList   
(2) DimList -> ε DimList'  
(3) DimList' -> Dim DimList'
(4) DimList' -> ε  
(5) Dim -> [ CONST ]
```

And, in the script that I am reading, it says that the function `FIRST(ε DimList')` gives `{#, [}`. But, how?

My guess is that since the right side of (2) begins with `ε`, it skips epsilon and takes `FIRST(DimList')` which is, considering (3) and (5), equal to `{[}`, BUT also, because of (4), takes `FOLLOW(DimList')` which is `{#}`.

Other way it could be is that, since (2) begins with `ε` it skips epsilon and takes `FIRST(DimList')` BUT ALSO takes FOLLOW(DimList) from (2)...

First one makes more sense to me, though I'm still in the process of learning basics of LL(1) grammars so I would appreciate if someone takes the time to make this clear, thank you.

EDIT: And, of course, it could be that neither of these is true.

Answer (score 1):

The usual definition of the FIRST function would result in `FIRST(Dimlist)` (or, if you like, `FIRST(ε Dimlist')` being `{ε, [}`. ε is in `FIRST(ε Dimlist')` because both ε and `Dimlist'` are nullable. `[` is an element because it could be the first symbol in a derivation of `ε Dimlist`, which is the same as saying that it could be the first symbol in a derivation of `Dimlist'`.

Another way of saying this is that:

`FIRST(ε Dimlist' #) = {#, [}`

We usually then define the function `PREDICT`:

`PREDICT(ω) = FIRST(ω FOLLOW(ω))`

and we can see that

`PREDICT(Dimlist) = FIRST(Dimlist FOLLOW(Dimlist)) = {#, [}`

Here, `FIRST(ω)` is the set of strings of terminals (of length ≤ 1) which could appear at the beginning of a derivation of `ω`, while `PREDICT(ω)` is the set of strings of terminals (of length ≤ 1) which could be present in the input when a derivation of `ω` is possible.

It's not uncommon to confuse `FIRST` and `PREDICT`, but it's better to keep the difference straight.

Note that all of these functions can be generalized to strings of maximum length `k`, which are usually written `FIRSTk`, `FOLLOWk` and `PREDICTk`, and the definition of `PREDICTk` is  similar to the above:

`PREDICTk(ω) = FIRSTk(ω FOLLOWk(ω))`